# How to get user's input of SQL query in R

Tags: sql, r, oracle-sqldeveloper, rscript

I am working on a R script that uses the RJDBC library to parse Oracle SQL queries.

Instead of hardcoding the STUDENT_ID in SQL, I want to take the  user's input only for the column STUDENT_ID in R, and the same I want to pass to the SQL query below and that writes the table into CSV
Can someone assist me with this?

**SQL**

```
SELECT STUDENT
   FROM TABLE1
   WHERE STUDENT_ID ='1680',
   AND STUDENT_CLASS = '10'
```

**Rscript**

```
library(RJDBC)
jar_path = JDBC("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver", classPath = "Documents/ojdbc6.jar")

connection_details = dbConnect(jar_path, "jdbcDriver, "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//database.hostname.com:port/service_name_or_sid", "username", "password")")

student_id = dbGetQuery(connection_details, 'SELECT STUDENT
   FROM TABLE1
   WHERE STUDENT_ID ='1680',
   AND STUDENT_CLASS = '10')

csv_report = write.csv(student_id, 'path')
```

Comment: I'm more familiar with `DBI`/`odbc` than `RJDBC`, but in case it still applies ... read about "parameter binding" at https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/, which would translate into `dbGetQuery(con, "select student from table1 where student_id=? and student_class=?", params=list('1680','10'))`.

Comment: @r2evans, Thank you. Could you help me how to get user's input here?

Comment: perhaps `readline`