# How to prompt an user for a STUDENT_ID in SQL integrated with R

Tags: sql, r, oracle-sqldeveloper, rscript

I want to extend my own post from : [How to get user's input of SQL query in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73112477/how-to-get-users-input-of-sql-query-in-r?noredirect=1#comment129146476_73112477)

I have already a sqlQuery, which I want to integerate with R script using the package 'RODBC'

Need help on :
I want to prompt a user for a 'STUDENT_ID' and print the results in the console?

Note: At present, I have hard coded the 'STUDENT_ID'

**R**'

```
library(RODBC)
library(sqldf)


#DB connections
connection_details<-odbcConnect("db",believeNRows=FALSE)

query <- paste('SELECT STUDENT
   FROM TABLE1
   WHERE STUDENT_ID ='1680',
   AND STUDENT_CLASS = '10')

results= sqlQuery(connection_details, query)
print(results)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an answer for your reference.

```
query <- paste("SELECT STUDENT
   FROM TABLE1
   WHERE STUDENT_ID ='###ID###' AND STUDENT_CLASS = '10'")

ID <- readline(prompt="Enter ID: ")
query=gsub("###ID###", ID, query)

results= sqlQuery(connection_details, query)
print(results)
```

Comment: Thank you, will this work, if the user inputs a string value? because it does not work if I input a value ''10-567055'

Comment: The input is a string. we may need to convert to the right type. Thanks,

Comment: Here is for your reference. You may check the input.

Comment: ID <- readline(prompt="Enter ID: ") ; 
print(ID)